# using while loop with nokogiri gem to navigate to next page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web-scraping, nokogiri, screen-scraping

Here is my code for next page

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.asklaila.com/search/Pune/-/Electrician/10?searchNearby=false&v=listing"))
 c=  doc.css('.resultTitle').collect {|node| node.text.strip}

while a = doc.at('a.btnNextPre')
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(a[:href]))
    c=  doc.css('.resultTitle').collect {|node| node.text.strip}
end
```

I want to scrape the data of all pages.But I am getting data of first page only.I am not getting data of other pages.Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code not targetting to proper class. In your while loop your are targetting to `a.btnNextPre` but class `btnNextPre` belongs to `li` tag so it should be `li.btnNextPre`. So try change your code something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

c = []
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.asklaila.com/search/Pune/-/Electrician?searchNearby=false&v=listing"))
 c.push(doc.css('.resultTitle').collect {|node| node.text.strip})

while a = doc.at('li.btnNextPre a')
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(a[:href]))
  c.push(doc.css('.resultTitle').collect {|node| node.text.strip})
end

c
```

Comment: I am not sure why it's not working for you. http://pastie.org/10447873 with working code

Comment: you haven't used while loop in your code........i faced an  error when i used while loop in this code

Comment: The problem is with your return. In your code you are trying to get all name in variable name `c` but each instance you are replacing `c`. You need to append result in `c`. and ruby return last statement by default. But in your case it's while condition that return nil. So try type `c` after your code and create a variable of array type. try paste my code in a rb file and run it. You will get result like http://pastie.org/10447928